# Open Source, multi language / unicode fonts?

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts

We need a selection of fonts that we can use in PDFs.

Our PDF library only works with TrueType fonts, and we want these fonts to be as multi language friendly as possible - i.e Chinese/Japanese support ideally, at the very least a wide range of European characters.

[unicode implementation: many fonts, or one large font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458566/unicode-implementation-many-fonts-or-one-large-font)

Has some recommendations (Gentium), but can anyone recommend a few interesting fonts that meet this criteria? **Especially a handwritten looking font**, that'd be great!

Answer (score 1):

http://mplus-fonts.sourceforge.jp/mplus-outline-fonts/design/index-en.html is a good selection of free Latin and Japanese fonts, to get you started. The fixed-width variant is especially good, being both useful in the console and also stylishly modern.