# Itext7: Display roman numbers

Tags: fonts, itext7, roman-numerals

I am creating a pdf using iText7. I want to display roman numbers. can you tell me which fonttype I should use.I tried using unicode equivalent of roman numbers like "\u2162" == III but it displays nothing on the pdf.

I am using the default font for the iText7. Haven't added anything specific font type. Which is the font type for the roman numerals.?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The font you're using probably doesn't contain the necessary glyphs for the romab numerals. Use something like FontForge to inspect the font. Also add the relevant iText7 code you're using to load in and assign the font to the text to this ticket, you'll have an easier time getting answers.

Comment: Updated the post. I am using the default font for iText7

Comment: default fonts aren't helpful: as default fonts one of the standard 14 fonts is used. Each pdf viewer has to support these fonts but merely for a limited character set which effectively is WinAnsiEncoding plus a very few additions. Explicit glyphs for Roman numerals are not among them.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using latin capital letters (I  V   X   L   C   D   M) to represent roman numerals if you want to use one of the [standard 14 fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_(Standard_14_Fonts)) in your PDF.

If you want to use unicode roman numerals, as [Samuel Huylebroeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6156384/samuel-huylebroeck) and [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl) commented, you need a font that includes the unicode roman numerals and use it with unicode font encoding `PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H`.

The following is a [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) example using a standard font and an [Open Source unicode font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1945315/9207529):

```cs
const string Latin = "The movie Saving Private Ryan was released in MCMXCVIII.";
const string Unicode = "The movie Saving Private Ryan was released in \u216F\u216D\u216F\u2169\u216D\u2167.";
const string Dest = @"C:\publish\RomanNumerals.pdf";
const string Font = @"C:\fonts\mplus-1p-regular.ttf";

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Dest, FileMode.Create))
{
    var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fileStream));
    using (var doc = new Document(pdfDoc))
    {
        PdfFont f1 = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA);
        PdfFont f2 = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(Font, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);

        doc.Add(new Paragraph(Latin).SetFont(f1));
        doc.Add(new Paragraph(Unicode).SetFont(f2));
    }
}
```